# Forcing navigation menu to retract when tapping outside the menu on the iPhone

Tags: css, navigation

See the menu at http://beta.jigsaw.org/ . I cannot find a way to have it automatically close when tapping outside the menu on the iPhone.

On the desktop this can be solved with something like this:

```
var clicked_menu = false;

$(".navbar-collapse").click(function() {
    clicked_menu = true;
});

$("body").click(function() {
    if(!clicked_menu) $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    clicked_menu = false;
});
```

I have tried using jQuery tap (http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/), but was not able to get it to work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Because I assume you want to hide the menu when an item is clicked I would do something as simple as

```
$(document).on("touchstart click", function() { 
     if ($(window).width() <= 767)
         $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

you might also want check if the menu is displayed beforehand.

Comment: This code is buggy, but using touchstart is the key.

Comment: Hi Steve, care to elaborate what the bugs were you found?

Comment: The menu would open and retract sometimes. I was unable to click links as the menu would close and the link would not be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some direction from Last1here, I have figured out a solution.

```
$("body > div:not(.navbar-wrapper)").on("touchstart", function() {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```